# Control Category of each user can post

Tags: users, user-roles, user-access

i need to know if has some plugin to control category of each user can post.

Exemple:

USER A - Only can post on the category A

USER B - Only can post on the category B

Thanks for TIPS!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have a plugin that does just that, it adds a category dropdown to the user profile edit:
[image]

Only user who can `manage_options` (admin) can see that field.

and once the user is logged in to post he sees this:

[image]

**Update**
Its now in the plugin repository http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-category/
enjoy.

Comment: wow.. very nice.. ty so much!!!

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work any longer... I'm attempting to fork it and fix it for modern versions of WP and PHP 8.2